# Does deleting row from base table affect view of that table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that deleting a row from view will delete that row from base table also. But I think it will be more surprised to know that how does deleting a row from base table affect on view?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting a row in a table will affect the results from regular views.

Views are not executed when they are created.  They are executed when they are referenced.  Each time you reference the view in the query, it is run again.  So, any updates to the data in the underlying tables will affect the view.

This does not apply to materialized views, which *are* executed when they are created.  To reflect changes in the underlying data, you need to refresh a materialized view.