# Does Truncating the Table Data Automatically Delete or truncate the View data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I created a view using the Members table. If I truncate the Members table will it automatically truncate the view data?

Comment: my-sql or sql-server?

Comment: A view is just a saved query, it doesn't (in general) contain any data. So if you remove the source of data used by the view then the view won't contain any results either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does deleting row from base table affect view of that table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608672/does-deleting-row-from-base-table-affect-view-of-that-table)

Answer (score 2):

A view is like a virtual table and does not have a Physical existence. A View is derived from an SQL Query which may pull data from a Single table or Multiple ones.

So when you do a query on a view, What it actually does is running the View Query on the background. So if you make any changes in the data on the Tables using the Underlying script, then the same will be effected automatically in the view

Comment: _"... does not have a Physical existence"_  Then how do you explain an indexed view? Be careful when making absolute statements.

Comment: @SMor For standard view result set is not stored in database, instead of this the result set is computed for each query but in case of clustered index the result set is stored in the database just like a table with a clustered index is stored